# A required class was missing while executing com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.9.0:configure: net/minidev/asm/FieldFilter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I'm using **jmeter-maven-plugin 2.9.0** with **maven 3.6.0**, when I run the mvn verify I get the following error:

> Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.9.0:configure (configure) on project performance-tests: Execution configure of goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.9.0:configure failed: A required class was mis
>   sing while executing com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.9.0:configure: net/minidev/asm/FieldFilter

I create on the same project a java class and I imported the class `FieldFilter` and works.

I try to verify with another version of plugin 2.8.5 and I get the same error.

POM content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>performance-tests</groupId>
    <artifactId>performance-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <hostName>${hostName}</hostName>
        <nrUsers>${nrUsers}</nrUsers>
        <rampUpPeriod>${rampUpPeriod}</rampUpPeriod>
        <jmeter-maven-plugin.version>2.9.0</jmeter-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jmeter-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateReports>true</generateReports>
                    <errorRateThresholdInPercent>1</errorRateThresholdInPercent>
                    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <hostName>${hostName}</hostName>
                        <rampUpPeriod>${rampUpPeriod}</rampUpPeriod>
                        <threads>${nrUsers}</threads>
                    </propertiesUser>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.8</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <excludedArtifacts>
                        <exclusion>org.slf4j:slf4j-nop</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>avalon-framework:*</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>org.apache.tika:*</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-datasource:excalibur-datasource</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-instrument:excalibur-instrument</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-logger:excalibur-logger</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>excalibur-pool:*</exclusion>
                        <exclusion>org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b5</exclusion>
                    </excludedArtifacts>
                    <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m</argument>
                            <argument>-Xmx1024m</argument>
                            <argument>-Xms1024m</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>`
```

Answer (score 1):

[JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) doesn't care in the slightest about what you have specified in [`<dependencies>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) tag, it has its own dependencies resolution and management mechanism.

You need to add the following lines to your *pom.xml* file:

```
    </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
    <testPlanLibraries>
        <artifact>net.minidev:asm:1.0.2</artifact>
    </testPlanLibraries>
</configuration>
```

Once you do this JMeter Maven Plugin will download the .jar to `target/jmeter/lib` folder and you will be able to use it in your test.

More information:

- [Adding jar's to the /lib directory](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath)
- [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri T, it works but only if I don't have settings.xml on the .m2 directory. If I add the settings.xml I get the same error.  Did you know what can be the problem?